# Semilinear subgroup $\Gamma L(1,2^n)$ of group $GL(n,2)$

Tags: group-theory, linear-groups

Let $\phi$ be an automorphizm of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ and $a \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$.
Let's consider a set of functions $\Gamma L(1,2^n) = \{g_{a,\phi} | a\in\mathbb{F}_{2^n}, \phi \in Aut(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})\}$ such that every $g_{a,\phi} \in \Gamma L(1,2^n)$ acts on elements of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ according to the rule
$$ g_{a,\phi} : x \mapsto \varphi(x)a, \text{ } x\in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}.$$
It's easy to see that $g_{a,\phi}$ is linear transformation, so $\Gamma L(1,2^n) \subset GL(n,2)$ and the set $\Gamma L(1,2^n)$ is closed under composition (multiplication) $\Rightarrow$ $\Gamma L(1,2^n)$ is subgroup of $GL(n,2)$ and it's called semilinear group.

I'm trying to describe subgroups $H < GL(n,2)$ such that $\Gamma L(1,2^n) \lneqq H \lneqq GL(n,2) $.

Do somebody know this problem or can give some links on semi-linear groups?

Comment: You surely mean to have $a\ne 0$?

Answer (score 1):

This subgroup is maximal in ${\rm GL}(n,2)$ if and only if $n$ is prime.

If $n=ab$ is composite then $\Gamma {\rm L}(1,2^n) < \Gamma {\rm L}(a,2^b) < {\rm GL}(n,2)$.

I would guess that they are the only such containments except possibly for small exceptions. I checked that it is the only containment when $n=4$.

For the maximality when $n$ is prime see Table 3.5.A of Kleidman and Liebeck "The Subgroups Structure of the Finite Classical Groups" for dimensions $n \ge 12$, and the tables for ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ at the end of Bray, Holt and Roney-Dougal "The Maximal Subgroups of the Low-Dimensional Finite Classical Groups" for $n \le 12$. In general for $n=ab$ with $b$ prime, $\Gamma {\rm L}(a,q^b)$ is maximal in ${\rm GL}(n,q)$. There are a couple of small exceptions with $n=2,3$ but not with $q=2$. These maximal subgroups are in the Aschbacher class ${\mathcal C}_3$ (semilinear groups).

Comment: why does $\Gamma L$ is maximal in $GL(n, 2) $ when $n$ is prime?

Comment: how do you check such containments in small dimensions?

Comment: I have added references for the maximality, but they are general results for maximal subgroups of classical groups and can be difficult to interpret in special cases. For checking I used Magma.

Comment: For $n = 2$ it is not maximal, but that's just because $GL(2,2) = \Gamma L(1,2^2)$.

Comment: Also "W. M. Kantor. Linear groups containing a Singer cycle. J. Algebra, 62(1):232–234, 1980." The main theorem states that if $H \leq GL(n,q)$ contains a Singer cycle, then $GL(n/m,q^m) \trianglelefteq H$ for some $m$ dividing $n$. So $\Gamma L(1,2^n) \leq H \leq GL(n,2)$ implies $GL(n/m,2^m) \leq H \leq \Gamma L(n/m,2^m)$ for some $m$ dividing $n$.